# how would I open a page when facebook like button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am in the process of creating a plugin to use on my wordpress blog. I would like to include a facebook like button where by when a user clicks the like button a div shows up with some content.just like this plugin does but not a dialog.

[here is an example functionality of what I am looking for.](http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-traffic-pop/full_screen_preview/142429)

I am thinking suing jquery.

```
$('#facebooklikebutton').click(function(){

    $('mydiv').show();


});
```

hope you get the point. 
Somebody please help.. this is much appreciated.

Comment: seems like your function should work just fine, what is the problem?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm pretty sure that forcing a user to like your page is against Facebook's TOS.

Is your intention to just show them additional content after clicking like?

Comment: @lynks, it should but it does not. @ ron you are right. I will also include the waiting time just like the example show... is there a way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the facebook js sdk you can use edge.create and edge.remove events. ie.

```
//listen for page like
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",
    function(response){
        alert("you liked the page");
    }
);

//listen for page unlike
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",
    function(response){
        alert("you unliked the page");
    }
);
```

how to set up sdk here -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

documentation on detecting likes here -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
<div id="showMyId"></div>

CSS
#showMyId{
 width: 50px; // your size here
 height: 5px; // your size here
 background-color: #000; //black color
 display: none;
}

JQUERY
$(function(){

$('#facebook_like_id').on('click', function(e){

$('#showMyId').show('slow/fast');
$('#showMyId').slideDown('slow/fast');

e.preventDefault();

});

})
```